# android uninstall package from within device

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I need to uninstall some package on my Android phone. This app is not listed by the Application Manager
Using *Terminal Emulator*, I can see the package using `pm list packages | grep com.mycompany.mypackage`
However `pm uninstall com.mycompany.mypackage` gives me

```
Failed to connect to dumpstate server
Killed
```

Since `pm` sees the package I would think I am not that far.
I also tried `abd uninstall com.mycompany.mypackage` which just stalls at

```
- waiting for device -
```

It may be noteworthy that this package is an Android Wear App. Hence it contains a mobile app which wraps a wearable APK (which gets deployed on the wearable). For clarity I am only caring about the phone for now.

Note: Rooting the device is not an option.

**Can I get rid of this package from *Terminal Emulator*?**

Comment: What is the output when you run this command in the terminal: adb devices

Comment: It is not showing any device

Comment: I think that is the problem. is your device in debug mode ? It depends on the devices but usually it's in settings/developper settings/ USD debugger mode should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go `adb shell` on Computer --USB--> Phone, which I was trying to avoid.
*Terminal Emulator* clearly doesn't have the same reach as `adb shell`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step to enable the debug mode on your device until you get something when you run

```
adb devices
```

http://www.companionlink.com/support/kb/Enable_Android_USB_Debugging_Mode

And try again with

```
adb uninstall your.package.name
```

Comment: The device is already in debug mode. Adb devices works from the computer but not from Terminal Emulator